# Fastest way to find if an array of object contains one of the tags

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, with each object containing a property `tags` that contains an array of strings

```
let item = {
    tags: [String],
    name: String
};

let queue = [item1, item2, ...];
```

I want to know find all items that contain a specific `tag(s)`. The brute force would be 2 for-loops:

```
function findTags(tags) {
    let results = [];
    queue.forEach(function (item) {
        tags.forEach(function (tag) {
            if (item.tags.indexOf(tag) !== -1) {
                results.push(item);
            }
        });
    });

    return results;
}
```

Is there a better than `O(N^2)` way?

Comment: Don't use forEach() on the inner loop, because there's no way to break out of the loop early when you find a matching tag. Also I think the if statement should be `if (tags.indexOf(tag) !== -1)`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/13565751/787140

Comment: we need to see you object literal because everything depends on data structure and type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) or just `Object` to store tags so you don't need to iterate tags array to search a tag.

Use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to stop iterate as soon as a match is found.

Since you are filtering the array, use [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```
var tagsObj = Object.create(null);
tags.forEach(function (tag) {
    tagsObj[tag] = true;
});

return queue.filter(function (item) {
    return item.tags.some(function (tag) {
        return tagsObj[tag];
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to implement one for `getFirst` and one for `getAll` function.

```js
var queue = [
        {       
        tags: ["tag01","tag02","tag03"],
        name: "name01"
        },
        {
        tags: ["tag04","tag05","tag06"],
        name: "name02"
        },
        {
        tags: ["tag02","tag04","tag06"],
        name: "name03"
        },
        {
        tags: ["tag01","tag03","tag05"],
        name: "name04"
        },
        ],
 getFirst = (...tags) => queue.find( o => tags.some( t => o.tags.includes(t))),
   getAll = (...tags) => queue.reduce((p,o) => tags.some( t => o.tags.includes(t)) ? p.concat(o) : p ,[]);
   
document.write("<pre> Result for getFirst:\n" + JSON.stringify(getFirst("tag04","tag02"),null,2) + "</pre>");
document.write("<pre> Result for getAll:\n" + JSON.stringify(getAll("tag04","tag02"),null,2) + "</pre>");
```

Comment: Bonus points for including `(...tags) =>` in the same answer as `document.write()`.

Comment: `p = p.concat(o)` no need to reassign `p`