# What is the best way to parse a complex JSON array?

Tags: json

I have a JSON object which is very complex and very big size. I know how to parse or get values. But I want to learn what is the fastest way to filter data from that JSON?

The actual JSON is very big and complex. To make it simple, I just created a sample JSON which looks like the follwoing. I want to filter only the "CompanyTitle" which is only locatated like "NY".

```
{   
    "Companies": [
        {
            "Url": "www.abc.com",
            "CompanyTitle": "title of ABC",
            "OfficeLocations": [
                "Online",
                "NY",
                "CO"
            ],
            "OfficeLocationsDisplay": "Campus/Online"
        },
        {
            "Url": "www.xyz.com",
            "CompanyTitle": "title of xyz",
            "OfficeLocations": [
                "CO",
                "NY",
                "IL"
            ],
            "OfficeLocationsDisplay": "Campus/Online"
        }]
}
```

Note: I already completed the parsing but it is very slow. So, I want to learn if there is any fastest way to figure out, I will use that instead of my parsing.

This JSON is loaded on page from a .NET Model. So, I need to do it form the same page.

Thanks

Comment: What language are you using and how are you currently parsing it?

Comment: jquery and javascirpt

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the highest performance way to filter a list of JSON objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565751/what-is-the-highest-performance-way-to-filter-a-list-of-json-objects-in-javascri)

Comment: Are you sure the delay is on the parsing and not on the transfer between server/client?

Comment: yes, i am sure. because, i have to filter that several times on the same page and based on that filters drop-down values are visible inside that page.

Comment: it would be better if you  can add the code sample and say where exactly do you think the issue is

Comment: Do you really need all of that JSON? Do you control the server side, and could you just send little parts on demand (several ad-hoc Ajax requests for very specific details)?

Comment: I was trying to do that. But for this case, I am allowed to work on this page only or to create an external js file and link with this.