# Filter large arrays with Javacript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs

Basically I have an array with over 20,000 objects. What I'm trying to do is filter this array based on some conditions.

```
const filtredData = array.filter((item) => item.car === true && item.airplane === 'yes' && item.isValid === true)
```

The problem is that as the array is very large, it takes more than 4 seconds to execute this function and I'm looking for a much smaller time. I looked for some references and found [loadash](https://lodash.com/docs/) sumby(), but it only works when you want to search for just one index.

Comment: Not enough context here, I think. Where is the code running, how often is the code running, and why is the array so large? There are some approaches I can think of, but they vary depending on the circumstances

Comment: 4 seconds for 20,000 objects? That seems way too much than it should

Comment: Also, [`sumBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sumBy) just **sum** the array, not filtering it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the highest performance way to filter a list of JSON objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13565751/what-is-the-highest-performance-way-to-filter-a-list-of-json-objects-in-javascri)

Comment: I call this code to render a table using React. I call this filtredData 30x at once.